# What does "snap your caps" mean?

Tags: meaning

In Barry Manilow's version of "Rudolph the Red Nosed Reindeer" what does "snap your caps" mean?

> Is it Elton? Is it Billy? Is it Sting perhaps?
>
> Oh you’ll never ever get it, don’t **snap your caps**.

Answer (score 8):

The phrase appears to date back to at least to 1940s America.

*[Take-off: American all-girl bands during World War Two](http://books.google.fi/books?id=WXZaAAAAYAAJ&q=%22snap%20your%20cap%22&dq=%22snap%20your%20cap%22&source=bl&ots=a2wzCu95vB&sig=50KflPYHzecqGCEG9ORFA5EU2QY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7zVaUMXVKsHi4QT38oDoBw&redir_esc=y)* by Tonya Bolden (2007):

> SNAP YOUR CAP: Lose your cool.

[*The book of Negro folklore*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=R6a0AAAAIAAJ&q=%22snap%20your%20cap%22&dq=%22snap%20your%20cap%22&source=bl&ots=IBfvJImf9c&sig=v4Fwcvvw0bZZSGiX-4JqJ13WPWw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7zVaUMXVKsHi4QT38oDoBw&redir_esc=y) by Langston Hughes and Arna Wendell Bontemps (1958):

> SNAP YOUR CAP : To become very angry. *The dozens made him snap his cap.*

*[American speech, Volume 20](http://books.google.fi/books?id=P9Q4AAAAMAAJ&q=%22snap%20your%20cap%22&dq=%22snap%20your%20cap%22&source=bl&ots=FvoUATGRx9&sig=beaXu9uwVdVZoM0CCBsu1RkKtRM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7zVaUMXVKsHi4QT38oDoBw&redir_esc=y)* (1945):

> SNAP YOUR CAP. Become excited, flustered.

Finally, here it is in a 1977 poem by [Maureen Owen](http://www.thing.net/~grist/l&d/lowen4.htm):

> ```
>       Don't crack up    Go koo koo    off the rocks
>       get soaked     Don't loose your marbles      Twitch
>       your tea     Be harried    License revoked.   Don't
>       hold your breath    Lose precious sleep.    Snap 
>       your cap    Pop your buttons    Blow a fuse    Short out!  
>       Don't go under    Freak off the scene    Drown your hopes 
>       & Pout    Don't let this old world get you down 
>       and others get your goat    Don't sink your ship 
>       Snap your cookie      Up a tree    Not wrapped too tight 
>       they'll say.   Don't come unglued    Be in a stew
>       Let a screw    come undone    Get sapped.   Don't go turkey
>       Bees in your bonnet   Cook your goose      Have bats
>       in your belfry    & worse    Don't go out of your gourd
>       Loose your cool   Let it throw you     Be bowled over
>       Come unstrung      Don't go batty    End up dotty
>       weeping doorsteps midnight phone calls Friends who
>       wish you'd sit up straight!
> ```

Comment: [**This**](http://jwelshnews.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/world-war-ii-era-slang-oh-how-times-have-changed/) identifies it as WWII slang, and [**this**](http://www.the-jazz-cat.com/jazz-slang-dictionary.html) list of jazz slang terms says it's the same as "blow your top". That makes sense to me: *cap* and *top* equivalent to head/reason, and *snap* as a rhyming term for break.

Answer (score 3):

[The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cCVnlIUTpg4C&pg=PA597&lpg=PA597&dq=snap%20your%20caps%20underwear&source=bl&ots=cROyL1MYbs&sig=vcyv44mhXnReqekgBqbg7YRznZE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RzRaUOvhMujL0QWDroGQDA&sqi=2&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=snap%20your%20caps%20underwear&f=false)

> **snap your cap** *- to lose your sanity* US, 1973

Purely speculating, perhaps it draws on [snapback cap](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100501135238AAVuxg7) *- a snap back hat is a baseball cap style hat where size of the hat is adjustable by a snap on the back.* Also [don't get your knickers in a twist](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22get%20your%20knickers%20in%20a%20twist%22&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=e88fa87c1f0f8ec2&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1379&bih=886), and (admittedly rarer) [don't snap your knicker elastic](http://bbs.22b.com/forums/showthread.php?7329-Advice-needed-beware-long-winded!/page2)

You can assume from Manilow's (hitherto virtually unknown) pluralising of *caps* that it's not a common expression.

Comment: I think the snapback cap arrived on the scene long after 1973. [This](http://toponlineinfo.com/snap-up-the-snapback-hats/) suggests at least the 1980s.

Comment: @bib: It's highly unlikely anyone will come up with a "first use" on this one, which I suspect is primarily just a meaningless alliteration. I'm just suggesting reasons why it's clinging to life. According to Google, about 1/5th of all instances on the Net today reflect Manilow's totally non-standard pluralisation, so it obviously didn't have much currency before. OP asked what it means, which *can* be answered - not where it came from, which probably *can't*.

Comment: Probably just my knee-jerk dislike of the snapback cap prompting me to act out. For some reason, plastic will never be a fashion statement for me.

Comment: @bib: Until I Googled *snap your cap* answering this question, I'd never heard the term *snapback cap*. But it's obviously familiar to many people, so it's at least possible the alliteration has helped revive/keep alive OP's expression.

Comment: I expect you are correct: *lose your sanity*, but what came immediately to mind for me was the old roll caps we used in our toy guns: https://www.shelburnecountrystore.com/product_images/c/IMG_1667-001__20326_zoom.JPG

Comment: If I was answering one person, I would say, "Don't snap your cap," but, if there was a group of people berating me, then "Don't snap your caps" might be more appropriate. (Plus, the plural _caps_ makes for a better rhyme with the previous line's _perhaps_).